# Facebook comments. This comment has not yet been published to Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-comments

When a user wants to publish a comment, such message appears:Facebook comments. This comment has not yet been published to Facebook. For example on this page http://baznica.info/article/v-indii-shariatskii-sud-prigovoril-pyatery. On a test server such message doesn`t appear.(test server contains a copy of this site). Facebook debug tool doesn't show any errors, except notices. But even after i fixed comments in such degree that notices stopped appear, this message is still  showing. In application settings I set up domain app: baznica.info and site url: http://baznica.info/. Sorry for english. English is not my mother tongue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545590/32453

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this page and select your app:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

And then click "settings" in the upper right, do you have the "moderation mode" set to "Let me approve each comment before it appears"?

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? (Asking you to log in, saying you don't have any pages? 404?) Do you have any pages that you would have comment moderation privilege for (and are logged in to Facebook)?

Comment: it's just blank for me.  Yes logged into facebook.  No pages that would have that privilege.  Thank you!