# Getting alert This comment has not yet been published to Facebook. Publish Comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook comment plugin. 
When i am trying to write comment it always giving me below message

This comment has not yet been published to Facebook. Publish Comment

How can i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Your link url got blacklisted. Facebook asks to prove user the post on his wall

Comment: do you have any links or documentation on this? esp. how to get whitelisted?

Answer (score 0):

This occurrence is possibly/probably related to the "like changes to confirm" button type behavior: [Facebook like button is asking to confirm the action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083996) which may imply some type of auto "anti gaming the system" measure has been imposed [hopefully temporarily] on your site... –