# FaceBook comments plugin: this comment has not yet been published to facebook. publish comment

Tags: facebook

I can't find any suggestions to solve this problem. When user try to send comment via Facebook cooment plugin on the website the message is showing: "this comment has not yet been published to facebook. publish comment". Why it's happend? how can i remove it? I researched whole internet to try to find the solution, but nothing!! Can anyone help pls?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17545590/32453